# Unir dos routers en VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

estoy creando una aplicación de [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js) que en realidad una serie de pequeñas aplicaciones. Mi objetivo es aislarlas unas de otras. Mi principal obstáculo en este momento son las rutas.

En este momento tengo un solo archivo de rutas, que se ve más o menos así:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {path: '/', name: 'portadaIndex', component: portadaIndex},

    // Rechazos
    {path: '/rechazos', name: 'rechazosIndex', component: rechazosIndex},
    {path: '/rechazos/conjuntos/', component: conjuntoIndex, name: 'conjuntoIndex'},
    {path: '/rechazos/conjuntos/:id', component: conjuntoDetail, name: 'conjuntoDetail'},

    // Login
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: Login}
  ]
})
```

Mi intención es que cada aplicación tenga su propio *router*, por ejemplo:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import rechazosIndex from './rechazos.index'
import conjuntoIndex from './conjuntos.index'
import conjuntoDetail from './conjuntos.detail'

Vue.use(Router)

const rechazosRouter = new Router({
  routes: [
    // Rechazos
    {path: '/rechazos', name: 'rechazosIndex', component: rechazosIndex},
    {path: '/rechazos/conjuntos/', component: conjuntoIndex, name: 'conjuntoIndex'},
    {path: '/rechazos/conjuntos/:id', component: conjuntoDetail, name: 'conjuntoDetail'}
  ]
})

export default rechazosRouter
```

Luego quiero importarlo y **agregarlo** de alguna manera al *router* principal. Mi esperanza es que algo como esto funcionara, pero no.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import portadaIndex from '../components/portada.index'
import Login from '../components/login/Login'
import rechazosRouter from '../components/rechazos/rechazos.router'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {path: '/', name: 'portadaIndex', component: portadaIndex},

    // Login
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: Login}
  ] + rechazosRouter.routes
})
```

Aqui obtengo un error que dice:

> `Uncaught TypeError: routes.forEach is not a function`

También intenté agregarlo *dentro* de `Router.routes` pero tampoco funcionó.

> `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined`

### Pregunta

¿Es posible unir `rechazosRouter.routes` con el router por default? ¿Si es así, cómo puedo unirlos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No se pueden tener dos objetos `Router` en [vue.js](/questions/tagged/vue.js).

Sin embargo la alternativa es muy elegante.

Hace uso de un operador de [*destructuración*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) identificado por tres puntos `...` (que había usado sin entenderlo cabalmente).

Este operador devuelve los elementos ***restantes*** de un array, es decir, aquellos que no han sido asignados en una *destructuracion*.

- Primero, hacemos un *array* o arreglos de objetos que podamos pasarle al objeto *Router*.

  Además de la ruta y el componente, podemos indicar un nombre y propiedades. O mejor aún, como sugiere atinadamente [**@Gustavo García**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59651/638), usar vistas anidadas. Por el momento, usaremos estas rutas sencillas.

  ```
  import rechazosIndex from './rechazos.index'
  import conjuntoIndex from './conjuntos.index'
  import conjuntoDetail from './conjuntos.detail'

  export default [
    {path: '/rechazos', component: rechazosIndex},
    {path: '/rechazos/conjuntos/', component: conjuntoIndex, name: 'conjuntoIndex'},
    {path: '/rechazos/conjuntos/:id', component: conjuntoDetail, name: 'conjuntoDetail', props: true}
  ]
  ```

  El operador `...` hace que los elementos que no han sido asignados en una reestructuración previa, es decir, el resto o **los elementos restantes** (en este caso, *todos*) pasen al array padre, que en el ejemplo es `routes`.
- Hacemos lo mismo para la ruta de la portada y para las rutas usadas en la acreditación.

  En `portada.routes.js` tenemos:

  ```
  import portadaIndex from './portada.index'

  export default [
    {path: '/', name: 'portadaIndex', component: portadaIndex}
  ]
  ```

  Y en `index.routes.js` podemos ver: 
      import Login from './Login'

  ```
  export default [
    {path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: Login}
  ]
  ```

Al final, el resultado final es este

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

import portadaRoutes from '../components/portada.routes'
import rechazosRoutes from '../components/rechazos/rechazos.routes'
import authRoutes from '../components/login/auth.routes'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    ...portadaRoutes,
    ...rechazosRoutes,
    ...authRoutes
  ]
})
```

Que es lo que queríamos encontrar.

PD: La respuesta es de [lcdss](https://forum.vuejs.org/users/lcdss/activity) en los foros de VueJS.

Answer (score 1):

No tienes por qué escribir un router por cada URL principal. Vue.js soporta las rutas anidadas; esto es, tener un endpoint principal y bajo esta, tener tantas rutas como necesites por medio de la propiedad `children`. Por ejemplo:

```
const router = new VueRoute({
  mode: 'history', // para usar la History API
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: PortadaIndex,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/rechazos',
          component: RechazosIndex,
          children: [
            {
              path: '/conjuntos',
              component: ConjuntoIndex,
              children: [
                {
                  path: '/:id',
                  component: ConjuntoDetail
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              path: '/otraruta',
              component: OtraRuta
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      component: Login
    }
  ]
});
```

Es importante que, todo componente padre, como `PortadIndex` y `RechazosIndex` y `ConjuntoIndex` tengan un `router-view` para que los hijos se rendericen allí:

```
<template>
  ...
  <transition name="fade">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </transition>
  ...
</template>
```

Comment: Pues tu respuesta contesta a otra pregunta que estaba a punto de hacer, muchísimas gracias. Pero mi intención sigue siendo la misma, aunque en algunas aplicaciones use _nested views_, me gustaría que cada una tuviera su _router_. En Django, así se hace y me parece una buena práctica. Pero tal vez lo que quiero no sea posible.